# Why onpress function not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

class file

```
 export class salon extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status : true,
      };  
    }

     _toggleModal(){
     Alert.alert('hello');
     }

}
```

I am using navigationoptions in my sidebar

**I am adding onpress function in touchable opacity and it does not work only touch**

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  {this._toggleModal}}>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: you forgot to call that method from arrow function body, use either `onPress={() =>  {this._toggleModal()}}` or `onPress={this._toggleModal}`

Comment: @MayankShukla already tried it but same error btw thx for the quick response

Comment: @MayankShukla when i try this  onPress={() => {this._toggleModal()}} I got error 
 LIKE This: undifined is not a function(evaluting't_his5._toggleModal()')

Comment: `TouchableOpacity` and `_toggleModal` is defined is same class? can you share the full code?

Comment: Both are defined in the same class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using arrow function like this `onPress={() =>  {this._toggleModal()}}`

Comment: I know this function working but it's me not working

Comment: it's my project but if you share your email id I will share my code throw email

Answer (score 2):

You should bind your function on constructor or in use.

in constructor:

```
export class salon extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           status : true,
       };  
       this._toggleModal = this._toggleModal.bind(this);
    }

     _toggleModal(){
     Alert.alert('hello');
     }
}
```

in use:

```
 <TouchableOpacity 
     onPress={() =>  {this._toggleModal.bind(this)}}>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Check out the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for the more information.

Comment: It does not work I got an error  undefined is not an object(evaluating'_this5._toggleModal.bind')

Comment: I made a simple example check out it. https://codesandbox.io/s/ly5my4kzz9 If this does not solve your problem, we should see your TouchableOpacity, Alert components to solve it, edit your question.

Comment: it does not work and I am also chang TochableOpacity to  TouchableHighlight but same error

Answer (score 1):

Try to call your function without arrow function like this: `onPress={this._toggleModal`}